# How to hide the "body" statement in css and javascript

Tags: javascript, css

but after a treatment i want to hide it so i did this:

CSS Code :

```
body {
text-align: center;
background: url(../images/greenbg.png);
color: #fff;
font-family: myriad pro;    
    }

 body#hide{
visibility: hidden; 
   }
```

But i cant't find a way to use the " body#hide" property in my javascript code .
Any idea please?
Thank you in advance

Comment: That should be a classname, not an ID.

Comment: And what remains displayed to the user if you hide the whole page contents?

Comment: Also, is `myriad pro` the name of the font? In that case, it's ***STRONGLY ENCOURAGED*** to put in quotes.

Comment: "How to hide the body"... I expected some other kind of question after reading that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

just use

```
document.body.id = "hide"
```

and the css rule you wrote will be applied to your body

Answer (score 4):

F. Calderan is right, but in this case to avoid any misunderstandings(with already declared IDs) it's better to use css classes.

For Example:

```
<style>
.inVisible{
visibility: hidden; 
}
</style>
<script>
 function HideBodyElement(){
    document.body.className = "inVisible"
 }
</script>
<body>
   <button onclick="HideBodyElement()">Hide body</button>
</body>
```